# Gradient Descent and an ascent direction

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent, quadratic-programming

Consider $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ such that $f$ is quadratic and convex. Meaning, $f(x)=x^TAx+b^Tx$ for $A\succ0$.

Conjecture:
Consider the Gradient Descent method with exact line search for minimizing $f$, with starting point $x^0$. I want to show that for every iteration $k\in \mathbb N$ then $x^0-x^k$ is an ascent direction. Meaning, when walking from $x^k$ towards the starting point we must initially ascend.

This seems very intuitive, but I just could not give a proper proof. I tried to assume otherwise and then use the notion of level sets (which are of course nested), but it got me nowhere. I also tried some other geometrical techniques that rely on the known "zig-zag" affect, again with no results.

I'm on this for several days now, so any new ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: What if you start at the solution?

Comment: Yeah, I though about this approach as well. If I start at the solution then of course that this is an ascend direction. But I could not utilize this observation to prove that this is an ascend direction for every iteration.

Comment: Sorry, I really mean to ask if you meant that $x^0 -x^k$ is a 'non descent' as opposed to strict ascent, as if you start at the solution then all iterates are the same.

Comment: Oh I see. The intention is to show strict ascent (as long as $x^0$ is not the solution).

Comment: I found the update formulas on page 7 of [these lecture notes](http://www.princeton.edu/~amirali/Public/Teaching/ORF363_COS323/F14/ORF363_COS323_F14_Lec8.pdf), and an illustration on the page after. You want to prove that the iterates cannot cross the hyperplane through the optimum $x^*$ orthogonal to $x^0-x^*$.

Comment: I tried using this observation, but I could not utilize it to prove that for every iteration $k$ then $x^0 -x^k$ is an ascent direction.

Comment: Just curious, is this a homework problem or your own conjecture (or other...)?

Comment: It's my conjecture. I'm working on a project and I want to prove convergence of one of the algorithms I developed. I encountered this issue and at first I thought it is straightforward so I left it aside. But now I see that it is not.

Comment: I added a numerical example which suggests that this is not true. The problem is reasonably conditioned, so I would consider this sufficient evidence that it is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming without loss of generality that $A$ is symmetric.

If $f(x) = x^TAx+x^Tb$ then $g(x)=\nabla f(x) = 2Ax+b$.

To compute the step size we find the $\lambda$ that minimises
$\phi(\lambda)=f(x-\lambda g(x))$. Since $f$ is convex, this is equivalent to
finding where $\phi'(\lambda) = 0$, or equivalently, where $g(x-\lambda g(x))^T g(x) = 0$.

Expanding gives $ (2A (x- \lambda g(x) -b )^T g(x) = ( g(x)-2 \lambda A g(x))^T g(x)$, and so
$\lambda = {1 \over 2} { g(x)^T g(x) \over g^T(x) A g(x) }$.

Hence the algorithm update formula is
$x_{k+1} = x_k - {1 \over 2} { g(x)^T g(x) \over g^T(x) A g(x) } g(x)$.

The following suggests that the result is not true. The value printed is
$df(x_k,x_0-x_k) = g(x)^T(x_0-x_k)$.

```
global A = [1 0 0 ; 0 2 0 ; 0 0 1/30] ;
global b = [-1 -1 0]' ;
global x0 = [0 1 1]' ;

cond(A)

# gradient...
function y = g(x)
    global A
    global b
    y = 2*A*x+b ;
endfunction

# one step of algorithm...
function y = next(x)
    global A
    global x0
    grad = g(x) ;
    lambda = 1/2*grad'*grad/(grad'*A*grad) ;
    y = x-lambda*grad ;
    # this is what we are checking...
    g(y)'*(x0-y)
endfunction

x = x0 ;

x0'
x = next(x) ; x'
x = next(x) ; x'
x = next(x) ; x'
```

Generates the following:

```
ans =  60
ans =

   0   1   1

ans =    2.7756e-17
ans =

    0.26327   0.21018   0.98245

ans =  0.11712
ans =

    0.48173   0.28367   0.95223

ans = -0.014054
ans =

    0.49311   0.24174   0.93246
```

Note the negative value of the directional derivative.

Comment: Actually, if you replace the ${1 \over 30}$ by $3$ you will get a better conditioned problem and the directional derivative is $\approx - 0.09$.

Comment: Thanks! This shows that the intuition for the 3D case does not necessarily holds in higher dimensions. How did you come up with this example? Did you follow any intuition or did you just tried to run some functions?

Comment: Hard to say exactly, I've looked at such things for decades :-(. Very loosely (and I mean **very**) it seemed unlikely to me that it was true just because if you 'jump across the valley' then the direction back to the starting point must go downhill first. If you live in two dimensions, then dog legs keep you from jumping, as such. Interesting conjecture, though. It also seemed plausible, so my first attempts were to prove it. Probably TMI, but I am avoiding doing real work at the moment :-).

Comment: Why is it possible (in higher dimensions) to "jump across the valley"? Isn't it contradicts the definition of exact line search?

Comment: No, the line search just requires the next gradient to be perpendicular to the last, in the plane this is a big restriction, in higher dimensions, less so.

Comment: I see. Since my last conjecture was proved to be false, it led me to another one that could give me better results in analyzing my algorithm. Again with exact line search (since it is obviously false for other line search methods), could it be that $||x^{k}-x^{k-1}|| \le ||x^k -x^0||$? Using your last comment, this is not guaranteed in higher dimensions, since the iterations could be "everywhere". I'm just interested in your feeling regarding that, please don't feel obligated to this.

Comment: I don't have a good guess on that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your generous help :)

Comment: Well, my best guess was that your last conjecture was not true, but I ran about 20 different test cases and in all of them it was valid :-(.

Comment: Same here. I find it very strange that claims regarding such well-studied subject that involve only quadratic and convex functions are hard to prove/disprove.

Comment: The more I look at 'basic' stuff the more I realise how little I know...